# awk not printing complete column value in csv file

Tags: python-3.x, shell, awk

I'm new to AWK, need help on below. I have below code to print 9th column value in CSV when false. The 9th column having 7 lines 
but its printing only the first line. Can someone tell me how to print complete 9th column value?

It is printin only "Test failed: text expected to equal /

```
FILES=$*
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "${f##*/}"
  echo "------------------------------------------------"
  awk -F "," 'BEGIN{print $f} $8 == "false" {print $9}' $f
  echo
done
```

My input CSV:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Conne$
1583830716746,1202,HTTP Request- Authorization TC01,200,OK,ZH 1-1,text,true,,530,354,1,1,1202,0,1124
1583830717967,59,ID_001_Wrong_PNR,500,Internal Error,ZH 1-1,text,false,"Test failed: text expected to equal /

****** received  : [[[
                {
                    ""status"": ""500"",
                    ""code"": ""500"",
        ...]]]

****** comparison: [[[{""seatReservations"":[{""passengerKey"":""PAX1"",""success"":""false"",""seatCode"":""50C"",""segmentKey"":""SEG1"",""...]]]

/",322,1023,1,1,58,0,0
```

output getting:

```
"Test failed: text expected to equal /
```

Expected output:

```
"Test failed: text expected to equal /

****** received  : [[[
                {
                    ""status"": ""500"",
                    ""code"": ""500"",
        ...]]]

****** comparison: [[[{""seatReservations"":[{""passengerKey"":""PAX1"",""success"":""false"",""seatCode"":""50C"",""segmentKey"":""SEG1"",""...]]]

/"
```

Comment: awk parses by default based on newline character, but you are expecting awk to somehow understand a field spread over multiple lines.. you can check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk ... or you could use python and see if its csv module helps

Comment: Sundeep - Thank you. But my requirement in Shell not in Python. I tried in python which is printing complete value.

Comment: When posting CSVs with fields that contain newlines you should show us the output of `cat -ev file.csv` so we can see which newlines are LFs alone and which, if any, are CRLFs because if you have a mix of both (LFs inside quoted fields and CRLFs at the end of records) and access to GNU awk then the solution becomes much simpler than otherwise.

Comment: I suggested Python because you have Python as a tag, for cli, see https://github.com/dbohdan/structured-text-tools

Comment: [@RamKrishna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8878135/ram-krishna) are you the same person who posted this question, [kotloram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13260423/kotlo-ram), but using 2 different accounts?

Comment: Interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61105737/sonarqube-quality-gate-status-check-fail-in-jenkins-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

As awk is not csv-savvy, you can not use awk for that without writing some kind of csv parser for it. There are some in the internets. You could also whip up some kind of a hack that works for your particular problem. Like this (well, these as I was too lazy to combine them) for GNU awk (for using `FPAT`):

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")+"  # using FPAT instead of FS, look it up.
    OFS=","
}                                   # if record has 16 fields (this is uncertain
NF==16 {                            # define the condition better to suit data)
    $0=$0 "\r\n"                    # use different newline
}1' file | gawk '                    # pipe this to another awk
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")+"
    RS="\r\n"                       # that uses \r\n as RS
}
$8=="false" {
    print $9
}'
```

Output:

```
"Test failed: text expected to equal /

****** received  : [[[
                {
                    ""status"": ""500"",
                    ""code"": ""500"",
        ...]]]

****** comparison: [[[{""seatReservations"":[{""passengerKey"":""PAX1"",""success"":""false"",""seatCode"":""50C"",""segmentKey"":""SEG1"",""...]]]

/"
```

The first awk expects the data to have `\n` record separators and for "whole" records it changes the newline to `\r\n` where as "the

malformed

data" has `\n`. The second awk then uses `\r\n` to separate records. The condition for detecting "good" and "bad" records is not adequate and needs better definition, that's a sample only and probably messes up the next record.

It's a hack, treat it as one. [HACK THE PLANET!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3CKgkyc7Qo&t=0m21s)